# Discriminating type based on presence of different properties?

Tags: typescript, class, modeling

I'm a `typescript` (and `js` for that matter) newbie, and am stuck on modeling a list of authors.

With an `author` property whose value is an array objects, I need to:

1. allow those objects to have personal name properties (family/given), or simply "name" (for orgs and such).
2. allow an optional "location" property (for publishers and org authors).
3. to auto-export to JSON Schema using `typescript-json-schema`, and to load the JSON and have it correctly typed, so I can get associated methods.

I can do this on the `Reference` class:

```js
  @Type(() => Agent, {
    discriminator: {
      property: 'type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: Organization, name: 'organization' },
        { value: Person, name: 'person' },
      ],
    },
  })
  author?: (Organization|Person)[];
```

... which does work:

```js
  Reference {
    id: "un",
    type: "article",
    author: [ Organization { name: "United Nations" } ],
    title: "The Title",
    issued: "2020"
  }
```

But it has the one limitation that it forces me to include a `type` property in the JSON input data to discriminate, which I'd prefer to avoid if possible. I do, after all, know that if there's a `familyname` property, it's a `Person`.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `typescript-json-schema` so I'll answer more broadly. TypeScript can be utilised to infer/narrow/discriminate types in compile time based on the existence of a property (see some examples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)). However compile time inference is used mainly for "code maintenance", and cannot be utilised as is to give runtime (i.e. JavaScript process) results, you'll need to add some logic that removes or adds that stuff yourself.

Comment: I suppose I could also just have a generic `Contributor` class, whose methods check those properties?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to export TypeScript objects into a JSON file/object. If that's the case you could just use the JSON.stringify() Method. It converts the object or list given as a parameter into a JSON string, which you can then save into a file as needed. For importing the file/object you can then use JSON.parse() which returns an object. This object is any by default so you need to implement a Method that checks for its type. This [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-check-type-of-variable) may help you with the implementation of that.

Comment: Actually, the reverse: these will be input files for a processor (the other input is a style, and the output formatted references, etc.), where I plan to support also YAML, and so potentially user editing of these input files.